# Use Beautiful Soup to scrape all questions a person has answered on Quora

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup, quora

How would I program beautiful soup to scrape all questions a specific user has replied to?

**Input:**
URL of Author
example: https://www.quora.com/profile/AUTHOR/answers)

**Output:**
Column 1: Question the author has answered 
example: "Lorem Ipsum Question"
Column 2: URL of the answered question
example: https://www.quora.com/lorem-ipsum-question

Column 3: URL of the answered question
example: https://www.quora.com/lorem-ipsum-question

Answer (score 0):

This script will print all answers/url found on the page. There's also infinite scrolling that's making POST requests to `https://www.quora.com/graphql/gql_para_POST?q=UserProfileAnswersMostRecent_RecentAnswers_Query` but I couldn't manage to get the data from it (you can see it in Developer tools -> network tab):

```
import re
import json
import requests


url = 'https://www.quora.com/profile/Nana-Bello-Shehu/answers'
html_data = requests.get(url).text

d = re.findall(r'window\.ansFrontendGlobals\.data\.inlineQueryResults\.results\[".*?"\] = ("{.*}");', html_data)[-1]
d = json.loads(json.loads(d));

for e in d['data']['user']['recentPublicAndPinnedAnswersConnection']['edges']:
    if e['node']['__typename'] != 'Answer':
        continue

    q = json.loads(e['node']['question']['title'])
    title = q['sections'][0]['spans'][0]['text']
    u = 'https://www.quora.com' + e['node']['question']['url']
    print('{:<90} {}'.format(title, u))
```

Prints:

```
Do pictures speak louder than words?                                                       https://www.quora.com/Do-pictures-speak-louder-than-words
Does true love exist?                                                                      https://www.quora.com/Does-true-love-exist-8
What picture made your blood boil?                                                         https://www.quora.com/What-picture-made-your-blood-boil
What are the before and after pics of people who are drug addicts for several years?       https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-before-and-after-pics-of-people-who-are-drug-addicts-for-several-years
What was the funniest thing you saw/heard today?                                           https://www.quora.com/What-was-the-funniest-thing-you-saw-heard-today
Are there any truly selfless acts, motives, or people?                                     https://www.quora.com/Are-there-any-truly-selfless-acts-motives-or-people
Which famous person in history who is idolized, was actually a horrible person?            https://www.quora.com/Which-famous-person-in-history-who-is-idolized-was-actually-a-horrible-person
What is something that you read recently and is worth sharing?                             https://www.quora.com/What-is-something-that-you-read-recently-and-is-worth-sharing
How do I get the attention of my crush?                                                    https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-get-the-attention-of-my-crush
What are some heart touching stories of best friends?                                      https://www.quora.com/What-are-some-heart-touching-stories-of-best-friends
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way for you i think is with selenium:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='c:/program/geckodriver.exe')
import time
url = 'https://www.quora.com/profile/Nana-Bello-Shehu/answers'

driver.get(url)

SCROLL_TIME = 2


last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")

while True:

    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")


    time.sleep(SCROLL_TIME)


    new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
    if new_height == last_height:
        break
    last_height = new_height

qbox = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.qu-pb--medium')
for qb in qbox:
    print(qb.find_element_by_css_selector('span.qu-userSelect--text').text)
    print('https://www.quora.com' + qb.find_element_by_css_selector('a.q-box.qu-cursor--pointer.qu-hover--textDecoration--underline').get_attribute('href'))
    print('\n')
```

Output:

```
Do pictures speak louder than words?
https://www.quora.comhttps://www.quora.com/profile/Nana-Bello-Shehu


Does true love exist?
https://www.quora.comhttps://www.quora.com/profile/Nana-Bello-Shehu


What picture made your blood boil?
https://www.quora.comhttps://www.quora.com/profile/Nana-Bello-Shehu


What are the before and after pics of people who are drug addicts for several years?
https://www.quora.comhttps://www.quora.com/profile/Nana-Bello-Shehu


What was the funniest thing you saw/heard today?
https://www.quora.comhttps://www.quora.com/profile/Nana-Bello-Shehu


Are there any truly selfless acts, motives, or people?
https://www.quora.comhttps://www.quora.com/profile/Nana-Bello-Shehu
```

And so on...

This script scroll to the end of the page and copy all questions. You can try to set lower **SCROLL_TIME** to make the script faster but sometimes the script will end before end of the page with shorter scroll time.

**Note:**

1. You need [selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/)
2. You need Firefox
3. You need [geckodriver](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) and now the script import it from `c:/program/geckodriver.exe` so if you add geckodriver to an other path you need to change the **executable_path**